# How can I use gsutil to only make my *.jpg and *.png images public?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with many subdirectories containing a variety of different files. How can I make only my images accessible publicly? The following is great for making everything public but I don't seem to be able to filter on extension.

```
$ gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://mybucket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using `gsutil acl ch`, which will preserve all existing ACLs on your objects and make them publicly readable.  This command should do the trick:

```
gsutil -m acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://mybucket/**/*.png gs://mybucket/**/*.jpg
```

Using the canned acl (i.e., `acl set -a public-read`) can remove other ACL changes that you've made.

Answer (score 0):

gsutil accepts [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames).

So this works fine:

```
$ gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://mybucket/**/*.jpg
$ gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://mybucket/**/*.png
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the -R option when you use ** wildcards. You could do simply: gsutil -m acl set -a public-read gs://mybucket/**/*.png gs://mybucket/**/*.jpg